# List<dynamic> json FormatException Invalid radix-10 number

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to import json from a remote API and can not figure out what the proper map method is. I have tried numeros variations, but keep getting a formatexception error.

My json output is a list (member_jsonj) with a map:

```json
    [
       {
          "member_json":{
             "nameTag":"@Gumdum",
             "memberId":"031e78f2-e644-422d-8510-7a8f10cee1fb",
             "memberName":"Gumdum",
             "memberEmail":"gumdum@calvinellis.dev",
             "likedDailyVerses":[78,79],
             "likedDailyComments":[94],
          }
       }
    ]
```

I am trying to fill my member MemberModel by calling a fromJson

```dart
final MemberModel member = MemberModel.fromJson(result as List<dynamic>);
```

```dart
factory MemberModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
   
    final memberId = json[0]['memberId'].toString();
    final memberName = json[0]['memberName'].toString();
    final memberEmail = json[0]['memberEmail'].toString();

    final result = jsonDecode(json[0]['likedDailyComments'].toString());
    final List<int> likedDailyComments = (result as List<int>).toList();
    final nextResult = jsonDecode(json[0]['likedDailyVerses'].toString());
    final List<int> likedDailyVerses = (result as List<int>).toList();

    return MemberModel(
        memberId: memberId,
        memberName: memberName,
        memberEmail: memberEmail,
        likedDailyVerses: likedDailyVerses,
        likedDailyComments: likedDailyComments );
```

Please, any help or pointers at this stage would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @julemand101 from the flutter discord channel for working with me on this problem and coming up with a solution.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

const jsonInput = '''
[
   {
      "member_json":{
         "nameTag":"@Gumdum",
         "memberId":"031e78f2-e644-422d-8510-7a8f10cee1fb",
         "memberName":"Gumdum",
         "memberEmail":"gumdum@calvinellis.dev",
         "likedDailyVerses":[78,79],
         "likedDailyComments":[94]
      }
   }
]
''';

class MemberModel {
  String nameTag;
  String memberId;
  String memberName;
  String memberEmail;
  List<int> likedDailyVerses;
  List<int> likedDailyComments;

  MemberModel({
    required this.nameTag,
    required this.memberId,
    required this.memberName,
    required this.memberEmail,
    required this.likedDailyVerses,
    required this.likedDailyComments,
  });

  factory MemberModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
    final json = jsonMap['member_json'] as Map<String, dynamic>;

    return MemberModel(
      nameTag: json['nameTag'] as String,
      memberId: json['memberId'] as String,
      memberName: json['memberName'] as String,
      memberEmail: json['memberEmail'] as String,
      likedDailyVerses: List.from(json['likedDailyVerses'] as List),
      likedDailyComments: List.from(json['likedDailyComments'] as List),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  final jsonList = jsonDecode(jsonInput) as List<dynamic>;

  final memberModels = [
    for (final memberModelMap in jsonList)
      MemberModel.fromJson(memberModelMap as Map<String, dynamic>)
  ];

  print(memberModels.first.likedDailyVerses); // [78, 79]
}
```

due to my server output of json in json, I had to modify his solution a little with:

```dart
    final json = jsonDecode(jsonMap['member_json'].toString());
```